# How to set SEQUENCE as DEFAULT in Postgres-XL?

Tags: postgresql, postgres-xl, postgres-10

I use Postgres-XL 10R1.
I created table `packs` and sequence `packs_id_seq` same SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE packs (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    name varchar(10) NOT NULL
) DISTRIBUTE BY REPLICATION;

CREATE SEQUENCE packs_id_seq
    AS integer
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
```

I tried to use packs_id_seq as default value for id column.

`ALTER TABLE packs ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT (nextval('packs_id_seq'));`

But have some problem

```
INSERT INTO packs (name) VALUES ('test');
INSERT 0 0
```

Why rows didn't insert?

So, I change clause for `DISTRIBUTE`.

```
ALTER TABLE packs DISTRIBUTE BY ROUNDROBIN;
ALTER TABLE packs DISTRIBUTE BY MODULO(id);
ALTER TABLE packs DISTRIBUTE BY HASH(id);
```

But have same problem again.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "serial" datatype here, so your create table will be like

```
CREATE TABLE packs (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    name varchar(10) NOT NULL
) DISTRIBUTE BY REPLICATION;
```

and now when inserting records,

```
INSERT INTO packs (name) VALUES ('test');
```

it will have record like

```
id | name 
1  | test
```